# Selecting all records from one table that doesn't have corresponding records in related table doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, orm, go-gorm

I am using GORM and PostgreSQL as my storage solution.
I can't find any way to query all records from one table that doesn't have corresponding records in related table. Let's take a look at these tables for example:

```
Computers
  id               int
  current_gpu_id   int (foreign_key to Gpus table)

Gpus
  id               int
  gpu_name         string
```

I am trying to select all gpus that are not present in any computer. I know that there are few options for that:

```
SELECT * FROM gpus WHERE gpus.id NOT IN (SELECT current_gpu_id FROM computers)
or
SELECT * FROM gpus left join computers on computers.current_gpu_id = gpus.id where computers.current_gpu_id is null
```

These queries works perfectly in query pgAdmin Query Tool but doesn't work in GO GORM code.

```
    gpus := make([]Gpu, limit)

    // Option 1
    db.Joins("left join computers on computers.current_gpu_id = gpus.id").Where("computers.current_gpu_id is null").Find(&gpus)

    // Option 2
    queryString := "SELECT * FROM gpus WHERE gpus.id NOT IN (SELECT current_gpu_id FROM computers)"
    db.Raw(queryString).Scan(&gpus)

    // Option 3
    db.Table("gpus").Select("gpus.id, gpus.sn, gpus.name").Joins("left join computers on computers.current_gpu_id = gpus.id").Where("computers.current_gpu_id is null").Scan(&gpus)
```

Is it a GORM bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried `not exists`?

Comment: Yes, I used that:
`queryString := "SELECT * FROM gpus WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *` `FROM computers WHERE computers.current_gpu_id = gpus.id)"`
 `db.Raw(queryString).Scan(&gpus)`
It behaves exactly the same as previous queries. I added 4 four gpus to database and it is returning all gpus except the first one.